# Confusion in xml attributes and attributes value comparision

Tags: c#, xml

I have some what confusion in XML ! my xml file is given below

```
<rootnode>
<childnode id="1" quantity="3" type="auto">0000-000</childnode>
<childnode id="2" quantity="3" type="prop">1111-111</childnode>
<childnode id="2" quantity="3" type="toy">2222-222</childnode>
<childnode id="3" quantity="3" type="auto">0000-000</childnode>
</rootnode>
```

I am creating one function that takes two parameter as arrays of attributes and attributevalues. Now I am little bit confuse how to compare the node's each and every attributes with each other ?? Have a glance at my code

```
 ComparableAttributes = new string[]{ "id","quantity"};

 ComparableAttributesValue = new string[]{ "2","3"};
```

As per my requirement i must be got two nodes (2nd and 3rd). Because attribute and attributes value matches to that particular node !

```
  public List<XmlNode> getXmlNodeList()
    {
        XmlDocument Xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        Xdoc.Load(Filename);

        List<XmlNode> xmlList = new List<XmlNode>();

        foreach (XmlNode node in Xdoc.SelectNodes("//" + Childnode))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ComparableAttributes.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                if (node.Attributes[ComparableAttributes[i]].Value == ComparableAttributesValue[i] &&
                    node.Attributes[ComparableAttributes[i + 1]].Value == ComparableAttributesValue[i + 1])
                    xmlList.Add(node);
            }
        }

        return xmlList;
    }
```

It gives me output for only two value ... ! If i want to make it dynamic then how can i iterate loop ? I mean how can i put up the condition ! I am just little bit confused !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost exactly correct. There are some small problems:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ComparableAttributes.Count() - 1; i++)
```

Suppose `ComparableAttributes.Count()` is `5`. Then this loop will give `i` the values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and then stop. But this is omitting `4`! The correct way to iterate here is either

```
for (int i = 0; i < ComparableAttributes.Count(); i++)
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ComparableAttributes.Count() - 1; i++)
```

---

The next problem is that in the `i` loop, you are testing *two* indexes, `i` and `i+1`- I suspect you put this in because in your example you were only going round the loop once.

---

Finally, and most significantly, at the moment you are accepting a node if *any* of the magic attributes are correct, but it sounds like you only want to accept a node if *all* of the magic attributes are correct. To do this we need to introduce a new variable which tracks if a node is good, and make sure to check every attribute we need to.

What we end up with looks like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in Xdoc.SelectNodes("//" + Childnode))
{
    bool nodeIsGood = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < ComparableAttributes.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (node.Attributes[ComparableAttributes[i]].Value 
                         != ComparableAttributesValue[i])
        {
            // the attribute doesn't have the required value
            // so this node is no good
            nodeIsGood = false;
            // and there's no point checking any more attributes
            break;
        }
    }

    if (nodeIsGood)
        xmlList.Add(node);
}
```

Give that a go and see if it works.